# Can i change one image on click without changing other images?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Im trying to make multiple images with same class.

[image]

I want to change image on another one when clicking on one of the them but i don`t want to change all of them only that one i clicked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be able to help answer your question, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

by using javascript sure you can all you need to do is make a function that on click changes the image src to the given source

like `onClick("your_source")`

Answer (score 0):

You can if you add onlick="function()" to you html Example:

```js
function changeBlue() {
  $('.blueBox').toggleClass('greyBox');
}
```

```css
.redBox {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.blueBox {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.greyBox {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redBox" onclick="changeBlue()"> Click me</div>
<div class="blueBox"></div>
```